# AVCaptureVideoPreview Orientation iOS 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturesession

Since `[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setOrientation]` was deprecated in iOS 6, I am trying to use `[AVCaptureConnection videoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];` but I getting an error saying "No visible @interface for 'AVCaptureConnection' declares the selector 'videoOrientation.'" I have been trying to research for a AVCaptureVideo SDK for iOS 6 but I've had no luck. I also tried recreating the AVCaptureConnection but I had no luck in doing that. Here is a web reference to the code I am partially using. http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/

Answer (score 1):

Wow. Boy do I feel stupid `[AVCaptureConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientation];`